# Booting says "read error" randomly

Tags: boot, grub2

Every time I try to boot after installing Ubuntu I get "read error" and nothing else.

I was able to get into GRUB boot manager a couple of times randomly, but I haven't been able to in a while. I'm not sure why it would occasionally work.

Specs:

- mobo: Gigabyte z68apd3
- CPU: i3 3240
- HDD: 250 GB SATA WD
- GPU: Nvidia 550 ti
- RAM: 8GB

Comment: I bet that it is an issue with your HDD.

Answer (score 1):

The operating system was installed via UEFI (on the dvd) onto a system running with BIOS (not UEFI compatible). When I upgraded the BIOS firmware to a UEFI version, I fixed the problem entirely.

PLease note that I did reinstall the OS in legacy mode (BIOS) and still was unable to boot. It was only when I upgraded the motherboard to UEFI that I was able to boot into the OS.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that only works randomly and under certain conditions indicates a hardware problem or that the bootloader (GRUB) sectors are damaged. I would recommend using a live cd to do a backup of all your important files and try to install again. If you still have problems, then replace the Hard Disk.

Comment: ive reinstalled it many times.

Comment: ive also tried installing on another hard disk - im having the same problem with "read error"

Comment: I have a boot repair error dialog @ http://paste.ubuntu.com/7494410/

Comment: @user283352 have you tried the same disk but in another system/mother board?

Comment: i may have fixed the problem. i updated the BIOS to UEFI (it finally worked - i was having trouble updating it) and now its booting every time. even though I had installed ubuntu in legacy mode.

Comment: @user283352 can you include that as answer, and also cleanup your question so the relevant parts can be found by people with the same problem?